# php.ini problems? Increasing post_max_size and upload_max_filesize causes php to ignore POSTs?

Tags: apache, post, php

I have this weird problem.

Whenever i try to increase the post_max_size & upload_max_filesize to 2500M, my website seems to hang on me. Pages will continue to load, but any attempt to login or submit forms will not work. It simply ignores the POST as if it never was sent.

But, when i change post_max_size & upload_max_filesize back to 2000M, the website behaves normally and allows POSTs to go through.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Im referring to post_max_size & upload_max_filesize inside my php.ini although i hope that wasn't stating the obvious.

Comment: You are uploading 2,5 Gigabytes of data using HTTP uploads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably [this limitation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) in (32-bit) PHP:

> Be careful not to exceed the 32 bit signed integer limit (if you're using 32bit versions) as it will cause your script to fail.